# Cauchy Definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using the definition of Cauchy sequences, I seek to prove that:

$\{cx_n\}$ is Cauchy (where $c$ is an arbitrary constant)

How would I prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\{x_n\}$? Presumably a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: yes, {$x_n$} is cauchy, my apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $c=0$, the claim is obvious. Suppose $c\neq0$ then. Now use the definition of Cauchy to get that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$ for $m,n$ sufficiently large. Now use the distributive property ($|c x_n-cx_m|=|c|\cdot |x_n-x_m|$) and define $\varepsilon_0=\varepsilon/|c|>0$ so that you can get the $c$ to cancel.